# Fill and Color Legend Disappear while Adding Layers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have discovered an unexpected behavior while playing with changing layers in a ggplot object. I start with an initial plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <-
  ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y =  Sepal.Width, color = Petal.Width, size = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(position = 'top') +
  scale_size_area('Size Name', max_size = 12) +
  scale_color_gradientn(
    'Color Name',
    colors = scales::brewer_pal(type = 'div')(7),
    limits = c(-3, 3),
    breaks = c(-3,  -1.5, 0 , 1.5, 3)
  ) 

print(p)
```

[image: Plot 1]

I then decide that I want to change the points layer to a points layer with a different shape, 21. Shape 21 has fill instead of color. However, I want to keep everything else the same. To save typing, I first remove the initial points layer, and then add the new one in. However, I find that the legend for fill does not display when it should.

```r
p$layers
#> [[1]]
#> geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_identity



p$layers[[1]] <- NULL
```

```r
p_with_name <-
  p + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = Petal.Width), shape = 21, color = 'black') +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    'Color Name',
    colors = scales::brewer_pal(type = 'div')(7),
    limits = c(-3, 3),
    breaks = c(-3,  -1.5, 0 , 1.5, 3)
  )

print(p_with_name)
```

[image: Plot 2]

However, when I add the fill scale without a title, or with a different title from the color scale, it display properly.

```r
p_no_name <-
  p + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = Petal.Width), shape = 21, color = 'black') +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colors = scales::brewer_pal(type = 'div')(7),
    limits = c(-3, 3),
    breaks = c(-3,  -1.5, 0 , 1.5, 3)
  )

print(p_no_name)
```

[image: Plot 3]

```r
p_diff_name <-
  p + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = Petal.Width), shape = 21, color = 'black') +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    'Diff Name',
    colors = scales::brewer_pal(type = 'div')(7),
    limits = c(-3, 3),
    breaks = c(-3,  -1.5, 0 , 1.5, 3)
  )

print(p_diff_name)


Created on 2020-05-28 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

[image: Plot 4]

Is it possible to add a fill scale with the same name as the color scale and have it appear? It would help me to simplify my code a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `ggplot2` tries to minimze the number of legend by merging legends for different aesthetics if they have the same name, ... . After some trials I found a hack to prevent the merging of legends and have two "identical" legends with the same name. I simply add a `NA` to the vector of breaks in `scale_fill_gradientn` which breaks the identity of the color and fill scales and prevents the legends from being merged. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y =  Sepal.Width, color = Petal.Width, size = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(position = 'top') +
  scale_size_area('Size Name', max_size = 12) +
  scale_color_gradientn(
    'Color Name',
    colors = scales::brewer_pal(type = 'div')(7),
    limits = c(-3, 3),
    breaks = c(-3,  -1.5, 0 , 1.5, 3)
  ) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = Petal.Width), shape = 21, color = 'black') +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    'Color Name',
    colors = scales::brewer_pal(type = 'div')(7),
    limits = c(-3, 3),
    breaks = c(-3,  -1.5, 0 , 1.5, 3, NA)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**EDIT**: "Clean" solution to the problem

```r
# clean solution
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, size = Petal.Length)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(position = 'top') +
  scale_size_area('Size Name', max_size = 12)

p +
  geom_point(aes(color = Petal.Width))  +
  scale_color_gradientn(
    'Color Name',
    colors = scales::brewer_pal(type = 'div')(7),
    limits = c(-3, 3),
    breaks = c(-3,  -1.5, 0 , 1.5, 3) 
  )

p + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = Petal.Width), color = "black", shape = 21)  +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    'Color Name',
    colors = scales::brewer_pal(type = 'div')(7),
    limits = c(-3, 3),
    breaks = c(-3,  -1.5, 0 , 1.5, 3)
  )
```

Comment: The issue is I want the scales to be merged and share the same title. The issue is that when they should be, they aren't. I think when I pass the fill scale in with the same name as the color scale, it tries to merge and fails. When I give it a different title, it draws the fill scale separately, so it appears.

Comment: Nevermind I see what you are saying. I can pass the fill scale in with the same title and have it not try to merge, (and subsequently fail) by using the NA in breaks hack. This is a solution for my situation, but I want to believe there is a more elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: Okay. I see. Had another look. As far as I get it the issue arises because you are setting the color to "black" for the plot with the fill aesthetic. Can't tell you what exactly is going wrong but my guess is that this is related to the fact that you globally specify a continuous color legend/aesthetic, then setting color to a discrete value and this breaks the merging of legends. Dropping the `color="black"` works fine. I added an edit to my code which probably is a cleaner solution and comes out with any hacks.

Comment: In my 'live' code dropping `color = "black"` unfortunately did not work, though in my example code in this post it did work. :/ I am happy with what you helped me with but man this is annoying.